# Passing props/state to/from parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

So I have a parent component and a log in component.

I want the user to enter their details and then hit submit and then store/pass those details around so they can be used by other components.

how is this best done in React?

for example I have this input field inside my log in component

```
 <p>
   <input type="text" id="playerName"  value={this.props.nameValue} onChange={this.props.handleNameChange}/>
</p>
```

Then I want to pass the value that is entered to the parent component

I have this function in my parent component:

```
handleNameChange(event){
    this.setState({nameValue: event.target.value})
  };
```

and in my return I have:

```
  return (
      <div>
        <LoginPage handleClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} handleNameChange={this.handleNameChange.bind(this)}/>
      </div>
    )
```

However, when I console.log(nameValue) I get undefined. any ideas? can add more code if necessary/relevant

Comment: Not an answer to your specific question, but: if you need parents to talk to children, use `props`. If you need children to talk to parents, use [`refs`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html). If you need to talk to anyone else, use a global store. And take a look at [this](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example you never pass `nameValue` to the child component.

Updated your example of rendering the `LoginPage`, passing `this.state.nameValue` into the child component via props:

```
return (
  <div>
    <LoginPage
      handleClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
      handleNameChange={this.handleNameChange.bind(this)}
      nameValue={this.state.nameValue}
    />
  </div>
)
```

Comment: how does this work when I need to call the function rather than trigger on a form submit?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach using state and props is fine.  Are you sure that you shouldn't just be using...

```
console.log(this.state.nameValue);
```

This is a working example

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            nameValue:''
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Child handleClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} handleNameChange={this.handleNameChange.bind(this)} nameValue={this.state.nameValue} />
        );
    }
    handleNameChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            nameValue: e.target.value
        });
    }
    handleClick() {
        alert(this.state.nameValue);
    }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
    render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" value={this.props.nameValue} onChange={this.props.handleNameChange} />
          <button onClick={this.props.handleClick}>Click Me!</button>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[JSFiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/bigalreturns/fwc8bq4x/1/)

Comment: how does this work when I need to call the function rather than trigger on a form submit?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, my answer doesn't have a form, let alone submit one.